# Correctly parse JSON in Spring Controller when value contains quotes

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, gson

I need to receive and parse some JSON in a Spring web service.  The JSON is sent over in an HTTP POST request and I have no control over the formatting, headers, etc of this request.  This is an example of the request:

```
{
"u": 1,
"t": "token",
"rental": "rental_name",
"address": "rental_address",
"arrive": "Monday, Jan. 1 2018",
"depart": "Wednesday, Jan. 3 2018",
"adults": 1,
"children": 0,
"guest": "guest_name",
"keys": "key location with "quotes" goes here",
"inquiry": "inquiry_id"
}
```

Notice that the value for "keys" has double quotes in it.

When I consume the request in my Spring controller, I understandably get the following Exception, because the quotes in that value are confusing it:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

Here's the method in my Spring Controller receiving the POST request:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/booking_new", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity newBooking(@RequestBody Booking payload){
    //Extract values from the generated Booking object etc
}
```

I can't receive the @RequestBody as a String and just escape the quotes because all quotes will be escaped, invalidating the JSON.

Is there any way I can somehow escape or remove the quotes within any values as the request comes in?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the json. Create a class matching this json and accept is as the argument in Post Request. And also check the content-type header

Comment: Yes, as the previous comment states, the error is related to the content type - perhaps you want to use MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON?

Comment: It is wrong JSON. `"key location with "quotes" goes here"` must be `"key location with \"quotes\" goes here"` to be correct JSON.

Comment: @pvpkiran @ PillHead I created the Booking class which matches the json already.  Unfortunately changing the content type as suggested doesn't work.

Comment: @Vadim Unfortunately I don't have control over that.

Comment: I understand. But source of it must be fixed to make real JSON. Otherwise you cannot treat is as JSON, but as a text and need to perse it on your own.It is possible of course, but code will be nasty.

Answer (score -1):

Although I didn't have control over the variables that comprised the JSON values, I found that I did have some control over the format of the overall POST request.

So I ended up formatting as XML instead of JSON as it's easier to get around the double quote issue.